# The number $2^{3^n}+1$ is divisible by $3^{n+1}$ and not divisible by $3^{n+2}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Prove that for every $n\in \mathbb N$, $2^{3^n}+1$ is divisible by $3^{n+1}$ and not divisible by $3^{n+2}$.

I was able to prove that $2^{3^n}+1$ is divisible by $3^{n+1}$ using induction.
First, I check whether the statement is true for $n=1$. The statement holds since:
$$2^{3^1}+1=9$$ $$3^{1+1}=9$$
Second, I assume that the statement is true for every $n\in \mathbb N$.
Finally, I take that $n=n+1$. From that, the original expression becomes $(2^{3^n})^3+1$, which is a sum of cubes, and the same as:
$$(2^{3^n}+1)((2^{3^n})^2-2^{3^n}+1)$$
As I assumed that $2^{3^n}+1$ is divisible by $3^{n+1}$, and one of the factors is $2^{3^n}+1$, the entire expression must be divisible by $3^{n+1}$, and so the statement is true for every $n\in \mathbb N$.

Now, I don't know how to prove that $2^{3^n}+1$ *isn't* divisible by $3^{n+2}$. Please explain how I can do so step-by-step, without using complicated terms.

Comment: So, $$2^{3^n} = (-1) + k\cdot 3^{n+1}$$ with $k$ not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: You missed the `+1`...

Comment: Yes, I skipped a part while typing it, it's ${2^3}^n+1$ instead of ${2^3}^n$. Edited the question.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii , yes, that's right. Sorry, I'm new this. I'll try to edit the question again with more details about what I already did and what kind of answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$A_n = 2^{3^n}+1.$$
The claim holds for $n=0$, and since:
$$ A_{n+1} = (A_n-1)^3+1 = A_n^3 -3A_n(A_n-1) $$
we have that $\nu_3(A_{n+1}) = 1+\nu_3(A_n)$, since $9\mid A_n^3$ and $3\mid 3A_n$ but $3\nmid (A_n-1)$.