# The number $2^{3^n}+1$ is divisible by $3^{n+1}$ and is not divisible by $3^{n+2}$.

Tags: divisibility

Old question:
[The number $2^{3^n}+1$ is divisible by $3^{n+1}$ and not divisible by $3^{n+2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012410/the-number-23n1-is-divisible-by-3n1-and-not-divisible-by-3n2)

However, I don't understand the answer from the question.
I know how to prove why it is divisible by $3^{n+1}$, but not divisible by $3^{n+2}$.

Prove it is divisible: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1591199.

Can someone please show me step by step how to prove is not divisible?

Comment: The duplicate says that $3\nmid (A_n-1)$, so it is not divisible by $3^{n+2}$. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the answer from that question, that's why I ask again.

Comment: What is v3? I don't get that part

Comment: An answer is also a part of [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70159/11619). Sorry to blow my own trumpet this much.

Comment: $\nu_3(m)$ is the exponent of the highest power of three $m$ is divisible with. So for example $\nu_3(15)=1$ and $\nu_3(162)=4$ because $3\mid 15$, $3^2\nmid 15$, $3^4\mid162$, $3^5\nmid 162$. A key property is that $\nu_3(nm)=\nu_3(n)+\nu_3(m)$ for all integers $n,m$. That, in turn, follows from the uniqueness of factorization.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but I still don't quite understand it. Because I just started learning discrete maths, so I don't know any complicated symbol and stuff. Is it possible to explain an easier way to do this question? Thanks

Comment: Really, Jyrki's explanation is very good and absolutely elementary. Counting how often a divisor $3$ appears, is completely elementary. If you post about divisibility by $3$, you should be willing to learn a little bit about it.