# Using $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ to prove $3^{n+2}$ does not divide $2^{3^n}+1$

Tags: induction

Prove for all natural numbers $n$ such that $2^{3^n}+1$ is not divisible by $3^{n+2}$.

My working for not divisible: Induction proof

Base case: n = 0
$$3^{0+2}=9$$
and
$$2^{3^0}+1=3$$
9 cannot divide 3, so base case is true.

Assume n=k is true. That means $B=3^{k+2}$ does not divide $A=2^{3^k}+1$. Now prove $3^{k+3}$ does not divide $2^{3^{k+1}}+1$.

Using $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$:
$$(2^{3^k})^3+1=(2^{3^k}+1)((2^{3^k})^2-2^{3^k}+1)$$
$$=A((2^{3^k})^2-A+2)$$

$$3^{k+3}=3\times 3^{k+2}$$
$$=3B$$

> That's where I need help!

**I want to show that $A((2^{3^k})^2-A+2)$ is not divisible by $3B$ by using hypothesis "$A$ is not divisible by $B$".**

Comment: You've made an error. $(2^{3^k})^2 -2^{3^k} + 1 \ne (2^{3^k})^2 - (2^{3^k} + 1)$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012410/the-number-23n1-is-divisible-by-3n1-and-not-divisible-by-3n2 ;https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135192/3n2-does-not-divide-23n1

Comment: We didn't learn about Lifting The Exponent (LTE) in class, so that's why I can't that for my answer. That's why I can't find any good proof without LTE

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: It is easy to see that $$3~|~(2^{3^k})^2-2^{3^k}+1$$ but $$9\nmid(2^{3^k})^2-2^{3^k}+1.$$

**Note**: To complete the proof, use the Unique Factorization Theorem of integers and count the multiplicity of the prime factor $3$. (This theorem requires only the Division Algorithm to prove.)

An alternative formal way to show that $3B\nmid A\cdot((2^{3^k})^2-A+2)$ is to use the [3-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order): Compare the $3$-adic order $\nu_3$ of the two integers, one has $$\nu_3(3B)=\nu_3(3)+\nu_3(B)=1+\nu_3(B)$$ and $$\nu_3(A\cdot ((2^{3^k})^2-A+2))=\nu_3(A)+\nu_3((2^{3^k})^2-A+2)=\nu_3(A)+1,$$ where the latter equality follows from the above suggestions and comments.

Now the induction hypothesis $B\nmid A$ shows that $$\nu_3(B)>\nu_3(A)$$
$$\Rightarrow \nu_3(B)+1>\nu_3(A)+1$$
$$\Rightarrow 3B\nmid A\cdot((2^{3^k})^2-A+2),$$ completing the case $n=k+1$ and the proof by induction.

Comment: Yeh, I wrote that on book as well, but I don't know how to prove that. I don't know how the RHS is divisible by 3.

Comment: I don't know how does "+1" makes it divisible by 3

Comment: Well, $2\equiv -1~({\rm mod~}3)$, which implies that $2^{3^k}\equiv -1~({\rm mod~}3)$. It follows that $(2^{3^k})^2-2^{3^k}+1\equiv (-1)^2-(-1)+1\equiv 0~({\rm mod~3}).$

Comment: Now writing $2^{3^k}=3r-1$, you may prove that $9\nmid (3r-1)^2-(3r-1)+1.$

Comment: I proved that $$(2^{3^k})^2-2^{3^k}+1$$ is not divisible by 3B, but how do I proved that $$(2^{3^k}+1)((2^{3^k})^2-2^{3^k}+1)$$ is also not divisible by 3B?

Comment: See the added note.